# wrapping content in a StackPanel wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

is it possible to wrap content in a `StackPanel`?

I know that we can make use of a `WrapPanel` instead. 
But for code modifying reasons, I must make use of a `StackPanel`.

So, is there a way to make the items in a `StackPanel` wrap after say 5 items...
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have to use a `StackPanel` instead of a `WrapPanel`?

Comment: there are certain features of stack panel tht we have customized..so we have our own virtualizing supported by our stack panel..i dont want to come up reinventing the wheel for virtualizing a wrap panel..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create nested `StackPanel`s which contain the required number of items.

In the example below, you have two rows, respectively occupied by the `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">` elements, which in turn each contain five items that will be displayed horizontally next to each other.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Item1 />
        <Item2 />
        <Item3 />
        <Item4 />
        <Item5 />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Item1 />
        <Item2 />
        <Item3 />
        <Item4 />
        <Item5 />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 33):

For me, a simple `WrapPanel` works just fine:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="500" />
```

Not inside a `StackPanel` or any other container. And setting **Width** to a constant value can be superior im some cases, because binding it to **ActualWidth** can prevent down-sizing *(e.g. when parent control is down-sized, WrapPanel is not)*

Comment: this is perfect for when you don't have a fix amount of items per row =)

Answer (score 9):

```
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                            <WrapPanel/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: :) I hear you, Ritch! ..but, it's hard to tell why there is such insistence on keeping the stackPanel without any context in the question! So there! Here's a typeof(StackPanel) with WrapPanel as an internal cancer!

Comment: Is this serious?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your scenario you could use a [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx). A few example can also be found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/uniformgrid-in-wpf/).

You can define it to wrap after 5 Items like this.

```
<UniformGrid Columns="5">
 <Button />
 <Button />
 <Button />
</UniformGrid>
```

Each Item will, however get the exact same width, so not sure if this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without a wrap panel. Maybe you can try putting a wrapPanel inside the stack panel - set its width to to the Actual width of the stack panel. You can bind it like `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=StackPanel1}"`

But this will be just a hack - i think wrap panel is the best suited for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I put a stackpanel over the button. It won't affect button background. Then in the VB code I used `Chr(12)`, to indicate a line feed:

```
Button1.Content = "first line" + Chr(12) + "second line"
```

You can add more lines using `Chr(12)`.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the best and easiest solution. Set ItemsPanel property.

```
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    </ItemsControl>
```