# Wrap Controls inside a stack panel

Tags: c#, wpf

I am adding few controls dynamically to a virtualizing stack panel control as children. I would like to wrap controls to next row if the controls don't fit in a row. How can I do that?

If I use Wrappanel then Virtualization will not happen.

So in short **I need the same wrap panel functionality using StackPanel**

Comment: Does it answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146428/wrapping-content-in-a-stackpanel-wpf#:~:text=6%20Answers&text=Create%20nested%20StackPanel%20s%20which,horizontally%20next%20to%20each%20other.

Comment: @TonyStark This will not help as the number of controls are not fixed on a row. They should get shift on window resize.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree. Getting `StackPanel` to wrap would mean it would have to understand stacking both horizontally and vertically at the same time. It doesn't, and I doubt there's any practical way to change that. What you actually want is a virtualizing `WrapPanel`. See duplicates. That said, I'd argue that if you have so many elements that you want virtualization, then `WrapPanel` is probably the wrong view to present to the user in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this,

[image]

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Button Content="Button" />
<Button Content="Button" />
<Button Content="Button" />
<Button Content="Button" />
<Button Content="Button" />
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: I do not want to use wrappanel as this will not support virtualization.

Comment: @user3722329: The `StackPanel` class doesn't support virtualization either. You'd have to be using `VirtualizingStackPanel` for that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am using VirtualizingStackPanel only. It is also not wrapping the user controls.

Comment: @user3722329: Your post says _"I need the same wrap panel functionality using **StackPanel**"_.